# Discretization of continuous 3 dimensional variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, discretization

I am currently working on Machine Learning classification problem that has  3 dimensional continuous variables (x, y, z ), I also want to add time(t) which is already a discrete variable. An example of what my data will look like:

```
     x                    y                    z                   t 
[0.1 ,2.6, 0.0]   [0.1 ,2.0, -3.0]    [0.0 ,5.6, 5.0]         1486033702474
```

Will taking the mean of each  continuous variable suffice ? 
Please how do I represent/format these variables to form my training data set in any ML library in Python?

Comment: Can you clarify the data type. Is the first vector x in time or each element corresponds to x,y,z? Expand on your data...

Comment: @mik all elements(x,y,z) will generate the same size of vector based on a time range say  t2 - t1

Answer (score 1):

Variables in computing are always discrete. The term "continuous" simply doesn't apply because computers are digital machines and can therefore only sample data at a finite rate. If you want to decrease the granularity of your data, taking the mean would be a valid option, depending on your situation. To take the mean of a list of data in Python:

```
mean_x = sum(x) * 1. / len(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Woody1193, I will try it out to see if something meaningful comes out.

Comment: If it doesn't work as intended, go back and think about what the variables denote. Try and figure out how to draw out the core of their meaning. It's vague but there's a certain bend required to massage the mathematics in this domain